# Problems with Data Explorer in RCP application

Tags: eclipse-rcp, birt

I embedded the Birt Report Designer in my RCP application, and I am able to open and save report designs easily, but there are some problems with the Data Explorer View.  None of the New... menu items appear in the context menu (all of the other context menu items appear).  For example Data Sources should have a menu item "New Data Source" but it doesn't.  A second problem is that Data Cubes does not even show up.  There is a selectable blank space where it should be, but the name is blank.

I reference the view in my Perspective like you would any other view:

```
layout.addView(DataView.ID, IPageLayout.LEFT, .2f, layout.getEditorArea());
```

Is there any other setup needed?

**Edit**

Turns out there is - I added org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.data which added most of the menu items and then added org.eclipse.report.designer.ui.cubebuilder to get all of the Data Cube stuff to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.data which added most of the menu items and then added org.eclipse.report.designer.ui.cubebuilder to get all of the Data Cube stuff to work.